# GDB [New Thread 0xABCD of process ABCD] (EDIT: can anyone recommend a different debugger?)

Tags: c, macos, crash, gdb, clang

I know similar questions have been asked already, but none of the solutions worked for me.

EDIT2:
I give up. Can anyone recommend a different debugger?

### How to reproduce:

1. Create a file like `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

2. `clang -ggdb3 -O0 hello.c -o hello`
3. `gdb hello`
4. `(gdb) start` prints:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f68: file hello.c, line 5.
Starting program: /Users/NAME/hello 
[New Thread 0xABCD of process ABCD]
```

And it does nothing from here. The only way to exit at this point is by quitting the terminal.

EDIT:
I found something new:
If I just start `gdb`(without `hello` as an arg) then I can run `(gdb) run` and it will print:

```
Starting program:
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
```

and when I then type in `(gdb) file hello`, it prints the following:

```
Reading symbols from hello...
Reading symbols from /Users/NAME/hello.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/hello...
../../gdb/thread.c:95: internal-error: struct thread_info *inferior_thread(): Assertion `current_thread_ != nullptr' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) n

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

../../gdb/thread.c:95: internal-error: struct thread_info *inferior_thread(): Assertion `current_thread_ != nullptr' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Create a core file of GDB? (y or n) n
Command aborted.
```

**Software:**

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- gdb(downloaded with brew) 10.1
- Apple clang 11.0.3

Comment: Is your executable running properly by itself?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That doesn't do anything. And typing `run` produces the same result(aside from the `temporary breakpoint`).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes.

Comment: Something I noticed is that when running `gdb hello`(step 3), it prints ```Reading symbols from hello...
Reading symbols from /Users/NAME/hello.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/hello...```

Comment: I reproduced what you did on my machine (gdb 9.2 and clang 10.0 though) and it works as expected